# Upgrading XCache on MAMP

Tags: drupal, mamp, drush, xcache

While trying to compile Xcache version 3.x for MAMP, phpize looks for a previous version of PHP which comes with Xcache 2.x

pwd: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/xcache-3.1.0

```
$ phpize
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

The issue appeared when I upgraded to OSX 10.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Building XCache against MAMP

1. setup command line
2. download and configure php source
3. build xcache

### Setup command line

You need to configure Bash to use the correct `php` command. Since you wanted to build against MAMP with 5.5.3 you can run the following command on your prompt:

```
$ export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

You'll also want to add the above to `~/.bashrc` to ensure future sessions use the correct php command — append to .bashrc:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now when you run:

```
$ which php
```

You should see: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/php`

### Download and configure php source

Download the php5.5.3 source from http://www.php.net/releases/. MAMP does not include the PHP source, so you have to provide and configure it when building extensions from source.

Extract the archive and rename the folder to simply `php` and place it at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/` — meaning you should now have the path `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/`.

When you run:

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php/configure
```

You should see a bunch of output. If you see an error double check you copied the source to the right location.

**Now** you can start building extensions against PHP 5.5.3.

#### Note: You may have to create the include folder

Since MAMP doesn't ship with source code they chose to omit the `include` folder — go ahead and create it since it's the conventional place to find php's source code when building extensions from source.

If you had a compiled version of php5.x located at `/path/to/php5.x/` then the php source code should be found at `/path/to/php5.x/include/php/`.

### Build XCache from source

After [downloading the XCache source code](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/ReleaseArchive) decompress the archive and `cd` into it:

```
$ cd /path/to/xcache-source-code
```

Assuming you have downloaded xcache-3.1.0 into OSX's Downloads folder you can run this:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/xcache-3.1.0
```

From within the XCache source code folder run these commands to build and install the Xcache extension:

```
$ phpize
$ ./configure --enable-xcache --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php-config
$ make 
$ make install
```

If everything was successful you will see `xcache.so` in your extensions directory.

Now you can enable the extension by adding `extension=xcache.so` to your php.ini. If you're using MAMP Pro it's important to edit php.ini via File > Edit Template > php.[version].ini — otherwise if you're using Basic you can run this one-liner:

```
$ open -a TextEdit `php -i | grep 'Load.*Config.*File.*=>' | sed s/'.* => '/''/`
```

Now, in php.ini search for the other "extension" directives and add `extension=xcache.so` to the list.

Check that it's installed by running:

```
$ php -i | grep xcache
```

You should see Xcache's settings. When you restart MAMP XCache will be enabled.

[Hat tip to JT](http://jacobt.com/post/42617402721/installing-xcache-on-mac-os-x-10-7).

### With 5.5.3 disable Zend OPcache

MAMP 2.2 ships with [Zend OPcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php) *enabled* for PHP 5.5.3. This could cause problems for XCache.

If you use XCache make sure to disable Zend OPcache. In php.ini search for **[OPcache]* and comment out the line:

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/…/opcache.so"
```

like

```
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/…/opcache.so"
```

Comment: Ok so first of all, i can't see the "include" folder. I have a lib folder though. So i did the same but in the lib folder. Secondly, i loose you completely at the "cd xcache-dir". I don't have an xcache-dir!

Comment: Updated answer to address your questions.